# Why Laravel validation not apply adn it bypass the vliadtion and store record in laravell 11

Tags: laravel

**So I want to validate the input field and it doesnot validate and directly store the record inside database**

> **My view Code**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('categoryreq') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
@csrf  
<div class="row g-3">
  <div class="col-lg">
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="cname" id ="cname" placeholder="Category Name" aria-label="Category Name" required>@error('cname') {{$message}} @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="file" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="cimage" id="cimage" placeholder="Upload Image" aria-label="Upload Image">@error('cimage') {{$message}} @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger form-control-lg" id="csubmit" name="csubmit" class="form-control" value="Add Category">
  </div>
</div>
  </form>
```

**my controller**

```
function categoryreq(REQUEST $req){
        $req->validate(['cname'=>'required|string',
                        'cimage'=>'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2048',
                       ]);
        $a = new tblcategorie;
        $a->category_name=$req->cname;
        $a->category_image =$req->file('cimage')->store('category_image');
        $a->save();
        return redirect()->back();
           
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the record is being stored inside the database?
Because if the input is invalid, you will be redirected to the same form page.

Comment: yes i enter numeric value it accept(later i use regex for string) but for file it upload the pdf format in database yes i am sure that it store the record into db i cross check again and the file store inside storage -app-category_image

Comment: I already used this concept in larave10 but recently i create new project on laravel 11 and this error occur

Comment: There's something strange going on here. I've initialized a Laravel 11 project and tried the exact same code and everything worked as expected.